# How would a ranger know he's being followed?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, ranger

Not long ago I was reading a novel from a popular DND author where a ranger concludes that they're not being *followed*, but *shadowed*. This got me thinking...

**What telltales would a tracker/scout/ranger look out for to know they are being followed?**

And what about being shadowed?

From a storytelling point of view, this could help adding details to the descriptions that I could be giving to my players. From a game-mechanics point of view, this could help me to do a better calculation for determining a DC.

Searching the web gave a few hints on real-life scenarios which could be useful for urban areas, so I'm more interested in wilderness scenarios.

Comment: What distinction is being made between being followed and being shadowed?

Comment: @Miniman The way I understand it is that the _shadower_ would travel parallel to the party. Of course, now that you ask, I'm not really sure.

Comment: Following a trail the creature's left is [tracking](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=track+definition); following the creature by watching the creature is [shadowing](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=shadow+definition).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Sensory cues;** Rangers are usually known for acute senses, so there's a lot of things they could detect. They could catch a glimpse of whomever is following them or hear the noises they make. The sense of smell isn't to be underestimated either; many real-life predators approach their target from below the wind to not give themselves away.

**Knowledge on animal behavior and nature;** birds and other animals acting strangely are a classic way to know something is off in fiction as well as in real life. Many birds, for example, let out distinguishable warning sounds, some even having specific ones for specific enemies. A ranger could hear the warning sounds and possibly even figure out what it is that's following them.

Answer (score 2):

I think distance, as well as the methods of perception/detection involved are the most vital pieces of information.  In a modern world, we mostly have mundane detection methods - our senses, knowledge of normal traffic in the area, knowledge of local flora/fauna, etc. to know what's actually out of place.  Even then, most of these things would assume that it's a human pursuer - therefore capable of more than just ducking out of sight and patience.

### Magic

If the shadowers are scrying or using magical detection methods to follow the party then it makes it harder to pinpoint the clues.  They can follow at a greater distance and avoid being noticed in the process.  They can even have a scout using Invisibility or Silence or other spells to hide them from senses completely.  Which brings me to...

### What's Left Behind

If the party isn't constantly moving in one direction all the time, every time then pursuit is harder to detect.  When the party makes camp, what is the shadow group doing?  Are they camping?  Are they leaving a fire pit, trash, bio-waste? The biggest problem most games encounter is the vacuum.  They don't talk about what's being eaten and when, how often, how they're getting rid of even biodegradable trash, etc.  So anytime the party lingers in one spot, those following have to be doing something too.  If a trail doubles back on itself (such as spiraling around the same hill) you can come across what's discarded on another part of the trail or even see would-be followers on another leg.

Not only this, but they need to entertain themselves, which can be an undue source of noise.  The party isn't always going to be followed by a roving band of shinobi-for-hire.

Answer (score 0):

If the ranger's animal companion is a bird, they can (and should) regularly send it flying up to scout.  Then cast *speak with animals* to interpret its message if it seems to have something to say.

If the ranger's animal companion is a wolf or something, there's still a chance it would notice a following or shadowing group by scent when it got upwind.